# Manually add admin bar

Tags: actions, admin-bar, wp-head

Does anyone know how to include the admin bar in a page template where `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` are not present? I'm developing a template other scripts and styles are just getting in the way. Rather than go through and dequeue all of the stuff I don't need, I've simple removed the two hooks altogether. All I want instead is the admin bar.

Thanks!

Comment: Admin bar is printed in the `wp_footer()`. javascript and style files needed by the admin bar are enqueued in `wp_head()` (or in `wp_footer()` if the enqueue order has been modified by a plugin/theme). Not sure if you can easily do what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

From Codex:

```
<?php show_admin_bar( $bool ); ?>
```

Comment: You should explain why this fix the problem. If you try to do it you will notice that your answer is not the answer. That function set the status of the admin bar but not print it.

Comment: I have to agree with this comment. This would only work if it was disabled and `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` existed in my code. Thanks for answering though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get it to work by calling the action that renders the bar in your template like this:

```
<?php do_action( 'wp_footer','wp_admin_bar_render' ); ?>
```

Comment: What should that do? `do_action()` doesn't take the callback as parameter.

Comment: It renders only the HTML and include CSS and js for the admin bar. As I can see in line 465 of wp-includes/plugin.php shown in the documentation it will execute the filter associated with that specific action of the footer. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/

Btw, I tested it myself since I had this issue it worked fine.